# Regular expression with word boundaries is not matching

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio-power-tools

I am trying to compute a regular expression to use with TFS Power Tools with the `DocumentWell` feature.

I am testing this in a console application at the moment.

```
Console.WriteLine(Regex.IsMatch(@"C:\User\User\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Project\", "\bProject\b"));
```

This is what I have tried (output is "False", so my regex string is `\bProject\b`. I have followed through the following link:

http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html

Which I thought that I understood... I really struggle with regex so could somebody help me out with this regex and explain what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use also a verbatim string for the regex, see [String literals on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

```
Console.WriteLine(Regex.IsMatch(@"C:\User\User\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Project\", @"\bProject\b"));
```

otherwise you have to escape twice

```
Console.WriteLine(Regex.IsMatch(@"C:\User\User\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Project\", "\\bProject\\b"));
```

See the difference of regular and verbatim string

```
string input = @"C:\User\User\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Project\";

string reg = "\bProject\b";
string regVerbatim = @"\bProject\b";

Regex r = new Regex(reg);
Regex rVerbatim = new Regex(regVerbatim);

Console.Write("Regular String regex: " + r.ToString() + " isMatch :");
Console.WriteLine(r.IsMatch(input));
Console.Write("Verbatim String regex: " + rVerbatim.ToString() + " isMatch :");
Console.WriteLine(rVerbatim.IsMatch(input));
```

Output:

> Regular String regex:Projec isMatch :False
>   Verbatim String regex: \bProject\b isMatch :True

In the regular string the last "t" of the Regex is deleted and also the empty string before the word, that is because the string interpreted `\b` as backspace and doesn't hand it over to the regex interpreter.

So either escape the backslash so that from `\\bProject\\b` `\bProject\b` is handed to the regex interpreter, or use a verbatim string, so that the string doesn't interprets the `\b`.